# ¿Se puede guardar un Activity en una preferencia?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent, programación-móvil

Estoy creando una App, ya la tengo terminada , pero me pongo a pensar como usuario si estoy navegando y de pronto se me urge cerrar la App o minimizarla, este inicia de nuevo con la `activity` que esta predeterminada en el `manifest de android`, y se pierde en la continuidad ¿Cómo podría hacer para almacenar esa `activity` en memoria , y continuar en donde me quede aun después de cerrarla o minimizarla?

Muchos juegos y aplicaciones que ofrecen una progresión por niveles, este suele quedarse donde el usuario las dejo.

Comment: se guarda en el savedInstanceState, el tema de niveles deberías guardarlo en un servidor.

Comment: no se puede guardar una Activity en preferencias ni en el bundle de savedInstanceState, en este se guardan valores necesarios para reconstruir la Activity pero no la Activity.

Answer (score 2):

**NO**, lo que se realiza es guardar los datos en preferencias esto para generar nuevamente la Activity pero no es posible guardar una Activity.

**Lo que puedes realizar es guardar el nombre de la `Activity` en preferencias como String y usar este para abrir la Activity** de esta forma:

```
startActivity(this, Class.forName("<nombre ultima Activity>"));
```

Para guardar y obtener el nombre de la Activity en preferencias puedes usar los métodos :

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mispreferencias";

public void saveNombreActivityPref(Context context, String nombreActivity) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("nombreActivity", nombreActivity);
    editor.commit();
}



public String getNombreActivityPref(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString("nombreActivity", "");
}
```

---

Guarda nombre (podrías implementarlo en el onDestroy() de la Activity):

```
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    //Guarda nombre de Activity.
    saveNombreActivityPref(getApplicationContext(), nombreActivityActual) {

}
```

obtiene nombre y abre `Activity`:

```
  //Obtiene nombre.
  String nombreUltimaActivity = getNombreActivityPref(getApplicationContext());
  //Abre Activity.
  startActivity(this, Class.forName(nombreUltimaActivity));
```

Comment: Teóricamente se podría, usando _ObjectOutputStream_ y _ByteArrayOutputStream_, pero como en Android se instancian actividades por _Intent_, guardarlos así solamente tuviera un valor histórico. ;D como básicamente cualquiera puede votar no tiene sentido de sentirse por ociosidades.

Comment: ¿? En verdad se podría?  =/ y ¿ ese valor historico como lo podría abrir? Sería buena idea agregaras una respuesta con lo que comentas y un ejemplo . =)

Comment: tiene razon, no se puede guardar una actividad, por lo menos no en una forma que facilita o permite al sistema Android de recrearla en el estado en que estaba cuando se cerró. Si se pueden guardar los datos para recrear el estado de la actividad en el momento de salida, estos se pueden recrear en _onCreate()_ la proxima vez que la actividad sea lanzado por _Intent_.

Comment: Ahora si estoy de acuerdo contigo =) hehe

Comment: Caso de "oops", para serializar la Acticity hay que asegurarse que implementa _Serializable_, algo que dudo. Sin embargo es posible de serializar, deserializar y recrear cualqquier objeto en Java dependiente de cuanto trabajo estoy dispuesto de invertir (Java es Touring-completo). 
El ejemplo es un poco fuera del tema aqqui, voy a ver si te lo puedo mandar por inbox (si encuentro una), @Elenasys.

Comment: muy buena tu respuesta compañero , pero el parámetro Context como lo obtengo , eso nomas me gustaría que me aclararas.

Comment: Si estas es una Activity puedes usar getApplicationContext(); donde lo llamarias?